# Dart plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dart

Does anyone know if there is a designer or plugin for Visual Studio for Dart, similar to the Dart Editor?

Comment: I've had convos with some members of the Dart community who have expressed interest in writing a VS integration for Dart.  So perhaps we'll see something in the coming months. :)

Comment: I've been working on VSCode integration recently! https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanTup.dart-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing yet for Visual Studio.

Comment: is this still the case?  For VS, not VS Code.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: [Dart Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code), my Dart extension for Visual Studio Code is much more complete than the VS extension I made (includes a working debugger and some flutter integration).

---

Original answer:

As nobody else seemed to be doing it, I decided to have a stab at this. It's very incomplete, but I've started working on an extension:

[image: Dart Visual Studio integration]

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69112f14-62d0-40fb-9ccc-03e3534e7121

The current version of DartVS available to install (v0.6) in Visual Studio is very basic and uses regex for syntax highlighting, and shells out to DartAnalyzer on a per-file basis for errors/warnings. This is not terribly reliable!

A new version of the extension (v0.8/v1) is in-progress which uses Google's Dart Analysis service and is much faster and more reliable, however it's still some way off release :(

A list of planned features for the next release can be found on GitHub:

https://github.com/DartVS/DartVS/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A0.8